# How can I assign variable name to SQL query alias column name?

Tags: sql

I want have aggregate query to count records between two dates and I want the result in alias column name as startDay - End Day i.e suppose I want record count between 1/st January 2015  and 5th January 2015 then I want that result under the column head as something like "1 - 5 ".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get better answers, consider adding some examples of what you're trying to achieve, as well as what you have tried sofar, in terms of queries.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: I do not think this is a good idea. You should go with a generic column name, It will save you a lot of hassle in the long run especially since users are unlikely to really understand what such a columns name means. It would be better to return the start and end dates as individual columns if the user wanted to easily see what dates the report was run for. However, it is an imperfect world and sometimes we get stuck with requirements that force us into less than perfect solutions. (But do push back this one and at least try not to do this as it is a horrible idea.)

In this case I am getting the idea that you want to vary the column name based on the dates that are sent in as parameters to the query, if the dates were from the 1st - 5th, you would want 1-5 if the dates are the 20th - 25th, you would want 20-25 as your column names. TO do this you need dynamic SQl which is a pain to write and even worse to test. It can also be a security nightmare. If you are bound and determined to do this stupid thing, then this is roughly how it would be done:

```
declare  @startdate date=  '2015/01/01'
, @enddate date='2015/01/05'
, @test varchar (10)
set @test = cast( day(@startdate) as varchar (2)) +'-' +  cast( day(@enddate) as varchar (2))


declare @Sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select top 10 id, field1 - field2  as ' 
+''''+@test+'''' + ' from table1
where date_entered >' +cast(@startdate as varchar(10))+
' and date_entered <= ' + cast(@enddate as varchar(10))

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Actually you should probably set parameter values for the execute sp_executesql  statement but I cheated because you would only be passing in dates which are hard to get to use for sql injection attacks. IN any event, do not consider doing this until you have read and thoroughly understood the following link:

> http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Dynamic SQL can be very dangerous and should be avoided especially when it is only cosmetics that are requiring its use. It should never be used lightly or without understanding the total implications of what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so with the lack of description here is my best attempt at trying to work out what you are looking for. If I am completely off I apologize.

Basically if you are looking for a custom column name and also looking to have multiple date ranges for columns. for example: If you want one column to have values between january 1st and january 6...then another column for dates between january 7th and january 13th...and so on and so on. Then you need to look at doing sub-queries similar to what I listed out below.

You would write the subquery to only select the data for your range that you are looking for then join it back to the main table you are pulling from.

NOTE: if you go with this method you are going to get a lot of null values popping up in your query so you will likley need to filter them out as you see appropriate but this varies greatly on how you do the joins to the sub querys.

```
SELECT 
ID
X.Jan1toJan6 AS [custom column name]
FROM
TABLE1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT 
ID,
[UpdateDate] as Jan1toJan6
FROM [table1]
WHERE [UpdateDate] BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2008-01-06') as X
ON X.ID = Table1.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually I need result something like this:

Comment: First Day week             First - Last Day Week   Number of applicants
05-Oct-15               Oct 5-10                         10
12-Oct-15               Oct 12-17                          50